# How to dynamically add filtered values for Mat-Select dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, formarray

Please let me know what I should do so that each row of the formArray does not change the values of the already selected values in the other rows?

Please note: Adding controls dynamically and getting the values correctly in the filters work. Its only when I change it, it goes and changes the other dropdowns as well. Thank you.

I have a **working** FormArray for which the controls are dynamically added at the press of a button. The controls have two dropdowns and depending on the first drop down the value of the second dropdown changes.

**However** when I add the next dynamic control and change the value of the second dropdown, it resets the value of the first already selected values too. I am using material `<mat-select>` for these.

My HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="allocationForm" autocomplete="off">
          <div fxLayoutAlign="start center" id="allocationsDiv" class="container row">
            <mat-card-title style="text-align: left;">Models
              <button mat-raised-button class="mat-raised-button-custom" style="padding: 3px;"
                (click)="onAddCars()">Add Cars</button></mat-card-title>

            <ng-container formArrayName="allocationsArray">
              <div *ngFor="let ctrl of allocationControls.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 250px;padding: 3px;">
                  <mat-label>Car Model</mat-label>
                  <mat-select formControlName="carModel" id="carModel"
                    (selectionChange)="filterCarModel($event, i)">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let models of distinctModels" [value]="models">{{models}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 350px;padding: 3px;">
                  <mat-label>Car Submodel</mat-label>
                  <mat-select formControlName="subModel" id="subModel" (selectionChange)="filtersubModel($event)">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let subModel of subModels" [value]="subModel.itemValue">
                      {{subModel.displayValue}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </ng-container>

             </div>
</form>
```

The `onAddCars()` method pushes new controls to the **allocationsArray**

My ts: for the `filterCarModel` method

```
public filterCarModel(e:any,ind:any)
  {
    let index = <FormArray>this.allocationForm.controls['allocationsArray'];
    var carList = Array.from(new Set(this.productsDTO.filter(x => x.productType === e.value).sort().values()));
    this.subModels = Array<Productdropdown>();
    carList.forEach(productLists => {
      const tempItem = new Productdropdown();
      tempItem.displayValue = productLists["carDescription"]
      tempItem.itemValue = productLists["carCode"]
      this.subModels.push(tempItem);
    });
  }
```

How do I filter the second control values not to change the already selected values in the first row of the **allocationsArray** in my code.
using angular 7x

the `onAddCars()` is something like this..

```
public onAddCars(){
      this.allocationControls.push(this.formBuilder.group({carModel: '',subModel:''}))
  }
```

Can you please let me know what I should do so that each row of the formArray does not change the values of the already selected values in the other rows? any help is appreciated. Please note: Adding controls dynamically and getting the values correctly in the filters work. Its only when I change it, it goes and changes the other dropdowns as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only has an unique variable "subModels" that use in all your form, so, you can do in this way.

One aproach is that subModels was an array or arrays

```
//declare subModels as array of any
subModels:any[]=[]
public filterCarModel(e:any,ind:any)
  {
    let index = <FormArray>this.allocationForm.controls['allocationsArray'];
    var carList = Array.from(new Set(this.productsDTO.filter(x => x.productType === e.value).sort().values()));

    //here declare this.subModels[ind] as an array
    this.subModels[ind] = Array<Productdropdown>();

    carList.forEach(productLists => {
      const tempItem = new Productdropdown();
      tempItem.displayValue = productLists["carDescription"]
      tempItem.itemValue = productLists["carCode"]

      //you push the element in this.subModels[ind]
      this.subModels[ind].push(tempItem);
    });
  }
```

Another aproach is that your productList was and array with children. Imagine you has some like

```
modelList=[{
      id:1,
      model:'Audi',
      submodels:[{id:10,name:'A3'},{id:11,name:'Quatro'}]
      },
      {
      id:2,
      model:'Seat',
      submodels:[{id:20,name:'Ibiza'},{id:21,name:'Panda'},{id:22,name:'Leon'}]
      },
  ]
```

I imagine a formArray with model and submodel, so we make two functions

```
getLine(data:any)
  {
    data=data || {model:'',submodel:''}
    return new FormGroup({
      model:new FormControl(data.model),
      submodel:new FormControl(data.model)
    })

  }
  addLine()
  {
    this.formArray.push(this.getLine(null))
  }
```

I am going to use an auxiliar variable and a [ngModel] in the form. See that the variable don't belong to the formArray, I use as auxiliar and use (ngModelChange) to give value to formArray.get('model')

My variable

```
model:any[]=[]
```

And the .html

```
<button mat-button (click)="addLine()">Add</button>
<form [formGroup]="formArray">
    <div *ngFor="let group of formArray.controls;let i=index" [formGroup]="group">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Model</mat-label>
            <!-- the ngModel is model[i] -->
            <mat-select [ngModel]="model[i]"
             <!--in ngModelChange we equal model[i] to event
                 and give value to group.get('model')-->
             (ngModelChange)="model[i]=$event;group.get('model').setValue($event.id)"
             <!--I need indicate that the ngModel is NOT belong to the form-->
             [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
             >
               <!--see that value is the "modelo", ALL the object-->
                <mat-option *ngFor="let modelo of modelList" [value]="modelo">
                    {{modelo.model}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>SubModel</mat-label>
            <!--this select use formControlName as ussuall-->
            <mat-select formControlName="submodel">
                <!--here I can use model[i].submodels-->
                <mat-option *ngFor="let submodelo of model[i]?.submodels" [value]="submodelo.id">
                    {{submodelo.name}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

    </div>
</form>
```

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efwqjn?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Eliseo..I have to accept to your answer as it was in the right direction for me to follow.Below is my code that I had to change

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let subModel of subModels[i]" [value]="subModel.itemValue">
                      {{subModel.displayValue}}
                    </mat-option>
```

and I have introducted the arrary for **subModelsany[][]=[];**
as you have indicated, but I managed to do with FormArray as opposed to your solution.